# sed from match1 to match2

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I have a text , that I want to print what ever between 2 words in that text showing only the first occurrence and disabling greediness if exist for example lets say that I have this text

```
    word1 XXXX
TTTT
YYYY
ZZZZ
    GGGG word2 JJJJJJJ word2
    ads
    word2
    adasdas
    word1
    asadadsasd
    word2
```

what I want is

```
    XXXX
TTTT
YYYY
ZZZZ
    GGGG
```

thanks

Comment: i am still noob , but after searching online i found this **sed -n -e "/word1/,/word2/p"** and it work but I dont know how to limit result only to first occurrence :(

Comment: I've edited the question because bold font is not printed inside code tags, and makes data sample weird.

Comment: ^ thank , I just wanted to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have a bit of a hack here. But it works.

Test file:

```
jfkakfakjskfj
    **word1** XXXX
TTTT
YYYY
ZZZZ
    GGGG **word2**
    ads
    **word2**
    adasdas
    **word1**
    asadadsasd
    **word2**
```

Output:

```
    **word1** XXXX
TTTT
YYYY
ZZZZ
    GGGG **word2**
```

Sed command:

`sed -n '/word1/,$p' file | sed -n '1,/word2/p'`

The first sed command matches all the lines from `word1` all the way to the end of the file and then we pipe it into the second sed command which matches all the lines from the beginning of the file (which we just piped into it) all the way until `word2` is matched. Its tricky but it works.

Comment: it worked like a charm , very intelligent way :) thank you , just a little thing , its greedy ! for example if there are 2 "word2" on same line it will take last one like ...word2 AAA word2 , is there a solution ?

Comment: @Leo92 Unfortunately I don't have an answer right now. But if I find one, I'll let you know.

Comment: ok thank you , I just find another solution **sed "s/ /\n/g" | sed "0,/word1/d;/word2/,$d"** , I cant explain it but it work , it just leave empty lines between it :)

Comment: @Leo92 It makes sense. You're basically replacing every space with a new line character. Just make sure this is what you want. Every word will now be on its own line. If you add `sed 's/ /\n/g' file` and pipe it in my command the same thing will happen.

Comment: yeah I didnt notice that because my input was stupid , it leave each word on new line

Answer (score 1):

I would choose `perl` for the job.

Assuming `infile` with the content of the question and following content of `script.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

die qq|Usage: perl $0 <input-file> <word-1> <word-2>\n| unless @ARGV == 3;

my ($word2, $word1) = (pop, pop);

while ( <> ) { 

    ## Remove last '\n'.
    chomp;

    ## Match range between first appearance of 'word1' and first appearance
    ## of 'word2'.
    if ( ( my $w1 = m/\Q$word1/ ) ... ( my $w2 = m/\Q$word2/ ) ) { 

        ## When 'word1' matched remove all characters but spaces until it.
        if ( $w1 ) { 
            s/\A(\s*).*?\Q$word1/$1/;
        }   

        ## When 'word2' matched remove all characters after it.
        if ( $w2 ) { 
            s/\A(.*?)\Q$word2\E.*$/$1/;
            printf qq|%s\n|, $_; 
            exit 0;
        }   

        ## Print lines inside the range.
        printf qq|%s\n|, $_; 
    }   
}
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl infile word1 word2
```

With following output:

```
     XXXX
TTTT
YYYY
ZZZZ
    GGGG
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer but I am using windows :( , beside I didn't thought that its going to be so complicated to use a script for doing the job